# MySQL receiving duplicate entries

Tags: mysql, join, duplicates

I have this query that is taking information from two different databases:

I'm using $query as the query string.

```
SELECT 
    blurbs.text,
    blurbs.timestamp,
    users.name,
    users.username,
    users.profilepic,
    users.id 
FROM 
    blurbs, users 
WHERE 
    (LOWER(blurbs.text) LIKE '%$query%' 
OR  LOWER(users.name) LIKE '%$query%') 
AND blurbs.is_private=0 
LIMIT 0,30
```

I am receiving duplicates of some of the entries in the blurbs database.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Add blurbs.user_id = user.id to WHERE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not joined both tables. You need to join it something like `users.id = blurbs.userid`:

So your query should be:

```
SELECT 
    blurbs.text,
    blurbs.timestamp,
    users.name,
    users.username,
    users.profilepic,
    users.id 
FROM 
    blurbs, users 
WHERE
    users.id = blurbs.userid
AND (LOWER(blurbs.text) LIKE '%$query%' 
     OR  LOWER(users.name) LIKE '%$query%') 
AND blurbs.is_private=0 
LIMIT 0,30
```

Or you can also use join statement like this:

```
SELECT 
    blurbs.text,
    blurbs.timestamp,
    users.name,
    users.username,
    users.profilepic,
    users.id 
FROM 
    blurbs JOIN users ON users.id = blurbs.userid
WHERE
     (LOWER(blurbs.text) LIKE '%$query%' 
     OR  LOWER(users.name) LIKE '%$query%') 
AND blurbs.is_private=0 
LIMIT 0,30
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select DISTINCT records as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    blurbs.text,
    blurbs.timestamp,
    users.name,
    users.username,
    users.profilepic,
    users.id 
FROM 
    blurbs, users 
WHERE 
    (LOWER(blurbs.text) LIKE '%$query%' 
OR  LOWER(users.name) LIKE '%$query%') 
AND blurbs.is_private=0 
LIMIT 0,30
```

Also, if you have any relationship between the blurbs table and users table, it is better to JOIN them on those fields than doing a cartesian product.

Comment: Well there are fields that are similar between the blurbs and users table, but they are not referenced in the query.  I'm not really very good with joins yet.  Could you provide an example?

Comment: Irrespective of whether they are either selected or filtered, if the fields are part of the relationship between the two tables, it is efficient to join as that would reduce the number of records in the worktable on which the filters are applied.